# Using python to do webpage login and scraping

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, ide

I'm new to Python and have limited coding experience. Recently I wanted to scrape some information from a website and was suggested that Python is a good language to use. I tried to search online and found several posts about this issue, but was not able to run their example codes successfully. I think some of them were caused by different versions of Python, lack of package, me using Python IDE incorrectly, or that I don't have admin account when installing, but I'm not able to identify them.

The thing I'm trying to do is:

1. login some website
2. after being redirected to another webpage, I want to click some button (like using the mouse), and a new window will show up
3. on the new window, after making some actions, there will be a button to print out the result as a pdf file
4. download the file.

My questions are

1. Can you please give me some advice about which version is better for the job above, 2 or 3? I was using 3, but many posts suggested using packages like scrapy, which I heard is now available for 3.
2. What IDE would you recommend for a new user that is easy to use and enough for the job? I tried Anaconda Navigator, but was confused about the three things it offered (jupyter notebook, qtconsile and spyder). Should I be  using the first one? I also tried Atom and use its script package to run Python code. I was confused about the Python package installing part. I tried to use "pip" in cmd, but I wasn't sure if it was successful because I don't have a admin account.
3. Can you give me an example code or point one to me, that can run successfully in the environment above? Many examples about "login website" use the website example.org, but it doesn't have the login feature.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

No problems is easy to make this with python and selenium module. I try to answer your questions.

1.- Always on 2.7, version 3 is ok but many aditional modules not work in this so alway use the popular.

```
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 11 2015, 17:47:16) 
[GCC 4.8.3 20140911 (Red Hat 4.8.3-9)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

2.- Why do you need an ide? For programming only a text editor is required in a terminal. Only if you want to make a megaproject use an ide.

```
 [hkeyland@localhost Escritorio]$ python testa.py
```

3.- First need to install all modules (selenium) that you require for my example. Read how to install modules via pip or download the zip and install

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

######################################## 
"""USER AUTH"""
username="user"
password="password"
########################################
 
########################################
"""LOGIN"""
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_window_size(1024,800)
driver.get("https://www_hackthissite_org/missions/prog/2/index.php")
element = driver.find_element_by_name('username')
element.send_keys(username)
element2 = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
element2.send_keys(password)
element3 = driver.find_element_by_name("btn_submit")
element3.click()
########################################
```

Comment: Hi hkeyland, thank you so much for your quick and informative answers. I will try the 2.7 version on my pc tonight so I have an admin account. I want

Comment: Hi hkeyland, thank you so much for your quick and informative answers. I will try the 2.7 version on my pc tonight so I have an admin account. I want an ide because I'm used to matlab kind of software where I can see the coding file and console at once. The terminal is definitely clearer for me as a new user, but I never used linux system, and I'm not very comfortable with doing actions with codes. For example, thank you for your code of logging in a website. To run it on a terminal, should I first save the code in a .txt file, and change it to .py? Then what should I type in terminal?

Comment: Sorry for the multiple comments. I mistakenly pressed "enter" to start a new line, but instead the system posted my unfinished comment. I was trying to edit it, but then missed the five-minute editing window... Thanks again for your help! I will try it tonight and hope you could answer my possible follow-up questions too. :D

Answer (score 0):

No problem, you can edit the file and save it with .py extension or change the extension txt to py without problems.

To run the script in terminal put

```
[hkeyland@localhost Escritorio]$   python your_script_name.py
```

And automatically is executed.

Comment: Hi hkeyland, thanks again for your answer. When I tried run the script in python terminal, it returned "invalid syntax". I searched a little online, and a post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961140/syntax-error-when-using-command-line-in-python) said that I should type it in cmd, is it true? I also tried to run it in cmd and it worked (after searching for why 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, and how to Add Python to the PATH Environmental Variable...). Maybe it's a windows thing? Is there a way I can run script in python terminal? Thanks again!

Comment: I just realized that maybe the cmd thing, rather than python .exe, is the terminal?

Comment: Hi hkeyland, when I try to run your code in cmd, it shows that " 
  File "login1.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "F:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 140, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "F:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: And that "Exception AttributeError: "'Service' object has no attribute 'process'" in <bound method Service.__del__ of <selenium.webdriver.firefox.service.Service object at 0x029F64D0>> ignored".  "

Comment: Sorry for the bad form of the message. I think the important one is "Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH". How can I do this? I think the geckodriver package is in the python folder and I've added the whole folder to cmd's PATH Environmental Variable... Thanks again!