# How do i Open an IDLE file (filename.py) in macOS terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, python-idle

I made a new file in IDLE named intro.py insdie it i typed print('Hello World') and saved it in Desktop, then i open python in the terminal and type in `python Desktop/intro.py` this happens:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1 python Desktop/intro.py
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why doesnt Hello World show up?

Comment: Looks like you file contains something you are not expecting. What would the output of the `cat Desktop/intro.py` be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [syntax error when using command line in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961140/syntax-error-when-using-command-line-in-python)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example