# SyntaxError: invalid syntax in python, why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, function, parameter-passing

This is the error i get:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1
& "C:/Users/myName/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.9.exe" "c:/xampp/htdocs/SD/UAS Prak/No1.py"
^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

---

And here is my full code:
[image: my code in VS code]
[image: my code is VS code2]

```
def proses(start,end):
peta = [
[5, 4, 6, 8, 9], 
[3, 2, 5 ,1, 2], 
[6, 2, 9, 9, 8], 
[5, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
[7, 8, 5, 3, 2]
]
path = []
kemungkinan = []
tempStart = start
for i in range(0,end[0]):
    if tempStart[0] == 0:
        tmp = peta[tempStart[0]+1][0]
        tmp1 = peta[tempStart[0]+1][tempStart[1]+1]
        kemungkinan.append([tmp,tmp1])
        if tmp < tmp1:
            path.append(tmp)
            tempStart = [i+1][0]
        else:
            path.append(tmp1)
            tempStart = [i+1][i+1]
    if tempStart[0] != len(peta) and tempStart[1] != len(peta) and tempStart[0] != 0 and tempStart[1] != 0:
       ...

    if tempStart[0] == len(peta) and tempStart[1] == len(peta):
        ...
print(path)
print(kemungkinan)
```

proses([0,1],[4,2])

---

What caused the error and how to fix it?
proses([0,1],[4,2]) is part of the code

Comment: You need to learn how to finx the code in your question. Yes the code in your question is bad syntax, but the error message doesn’t appear to relate to the code, as it’s showingg the input coming from stdin. What exactly are you doing when you get this error?

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: @balmy i run it in terminal?

Comment: @kiner_shah yep, it's fixed, thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

you need an indent after a function

```
def foo():
print('bar')
```

will give you an error because there is no indent
you need to do

```
def foo():
    print('bar')
```

and that will work.

Comment: But in my VS code, it's indented

Comment: thats not what you pasted

Comment: i cant tell you the answer if you haven't provided proper code

Comment: ohh okay, i'll edit it again

Comment: i added picture cause i don't know how to indent them here... does it help?

Comment: scroll up where?

Comment: sorry i didnt see the first screenshot

Comment: Please paste the complete code,so that community can edit and give you a solution. It's not indented. I can help you with that.

Comment: when i pasted the complete code, it said my post have too much code so. Also, how to indent here? @NikhilGowdaShivaswmay

Comment: ohh okay! @hbblue

Comment: can you type exit() in the terminal and then try to run the program again?

Comment: i think the issue is that you are already in a python interpreter see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13961140/syntax-error-when-using-command-line-in-python

Comment: Just ad Tab space on every condition and start of the function.

Comment: Yes, after seeing your edited code, this must be a problem with your running environment. I would prefer to run all python script inside an virtual environment.